# Regular expression to allow unicode characters in my email id

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

```
return Regex.IsMatch(strIn,
    @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
    @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
```

I'm using the above code to check for valid email id. But the above code is not allowing my email id with unicode characters. (For eg : Saànèéìòóù@gmail.com) But the above code is returning false for the mentioned email id. Can you guys please help me out in finding the correct regular expression.

Comment: How about using [`\p{L}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for letters? e.g. `[\d\p{L}]` instead `[0-9a-z]`

Comment: Sorry bobble. I'm quite new to regular expression . May I know where can I use it in above expression?

Comment: Emails cannot contain all Unicode characters, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844431/are-email-addresses-allowed-to-contain-non-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288271/email-regex-that-does-include-unicode-domains

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: While asking how to search for Unicode characters using regular expressions would be a valid question, the question of using RegEx to identify valid email addresses has been beaten to death in the answer section of the question linked as duplicate above.

Answer (score 2):

```
return Regex.IsMatch(strIn,
    @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=(?:[0-9a-z]|[^\x20-\x7E]))@))" +
    @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
```

Use this regex.